# Is padding in the structs always the same?

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer

1. Elements of the struct must be properly aligned, so struct can be padded with non-used bytes.
2. Size of the struct is always the same (since it's a constant expression).

So I presume compiler must somehow use the same padding every time such as:

- placing a single struct instance
- passing a struct instance by value to a function
- returning a struct instance by value from a function
- in the array of structs

If I'm correct with this presumption, can you please point me where does C standard says so? Are there any strict rules for padding placement that guarantee this property?

Comment: Do you mean "Do all instances of the struct within the same program have the same layout" ?

Comment: Padding and alignment are implementation defined. It can vary between compilers, and even between the same compiler on different platforms.

Comment: Theoretically the layout may change between different runs of the program

Comment: @M.M yes, that's the same question; but I can't understand how it can vary between program runs since sizeof is constant expression.

Comment: @Amomum "constant expression" doesnt imply anything about comparing behaviour of different runs

Comment: @M.M waaait, constant expression must be known at compile time, how can it change at runtime?

Comment: @Amomum It *may*  vary as far as the standard is concerned. In practice, implementations usually choose the "best" padding (smallest or fastest) for the platform .

Comment: @Amomum In addition to what M.M said, `sizeof` alone doesn't define how padding works. If we have `struct S { uint32_t a; uint8_t b; }`, and `sizeof(struct S) == 8`, then member `b` can be in any of the last 4 bytes. And if there is different `struct T { uint32_t a; uint8_t b; }`, its layout can be different from `struct S`, even if both have the same size.

Comment: You asked a question about standards , there's no distinction between compile-time and run-time in the standard. "run-time" could consist of interpreting the code (instead of compiling), or invoking a JIT compiler

Comment: @M.M I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: It is important to note that when using an executable that was compiler and linked out of the source code then the constants, this includes all non-variable length sizeof results, will not change under any circumstance.

Comment: @M.M Your first few comments could be misinterpreted as if they hold true for all cases. I'm just pointing this out to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: @2501 that's a common model of compilation but not required by the standard.

Comment: @M.M Well obviously. My previous comments allude to that.

Comment: @M.M actually I just found that the very definiton of constant expression in the 2005 draft mentions translation time and runtime, so I think you are wrong: "A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and
accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be."

Comment: @Amomum that text doesn't appear in the actual standard

Comment: @M.M unfortunately, I don't have an access to the actual standard but that text is the same in all drafts I could get (2005, 2007 and 2011, always in the chapter 6.6); it's really strange if it didn't go in the actual standard and yet somehow persisted in drafts.

Comment: @Amomum you should provide a document name and paragraph reference when providing such quotes. N4140 (freely available) would be a good source. Documents older than the final draft of C++11 are not relevant except in historical contexts.

Comment: @M.M okay, for a start I asked about C, not C++, so I looked in C drafts. Look for example at N1548 page 105 (paragraph 6.6) and you should find my quote.

Comment: Ah. I was thinking this was a C++ question, someone asked a similar question about C++ this week too. Sorry about that. OK, we'll distinguish "runtime" from "translation time", but as mentioned earlier, a JIT-compliation model may have both of those two stages happening when you "run" the "executable"

Comment: @M.M Does it really matter? Compilation is still compilation, JIT or not; since neither C nor C++ have something like JS eval, a constant expression should be an equivalent of literal, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

C locks down what the offsets of fields are in a particular structure type via the specification of the `offsetof` macro, in §7.17 of [this version](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) of the draft, which is describing the required macros in `<stddef.h>`.

> The macros are
>
> ```
> NULL
> ```
>
> which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; and
>
> ```
> offsetof(type, member-designator)
> ```
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression that has type `size_t`, the value of
>   which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by *member-designator*),
>   from the beginning of its structure (designated by *type*). The type and member designator
>   shall be such that given
>
> ```
> static type t;
> ```
>
> then the expression `&(t.member-designator)` evaluates to an address constant. (If the
>   specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.)

Since it is a *constant expression*, every use of a particular structure type must use the same offset (or this would all be completely crazy).
Two different struct types, even if declared the same, are not constrained by this to have the same layout. (For example, if the types were declared under the control of different structure layout pragmas, they would not be expected to necessarily have the same layout, yet the declarations would look *prima facie* identical. `typedef` is important!)

Comment: I've not got an easily searchable reference into the final version of the standard, but if someone has and it's moved or substantively reworded, please edit my answer add the correct location.

Comment: I was expecting an answer like that but comments to the question have reeeeally scared me by mentioning that there is no disctinction between compile-time and run-time in the standart and that constant expression - at least from language point of view - _can change_ at runtime